# NaN different from NaN in Go?

Tags: go

Can anyone explain why this happens? http://play.golang.org/p/QTaHpUm5P7

*Apologies for not pasting the code here as well but I'm on mobile ATM.*

I know I could use math.IsNaN() but I'm using the comparison operator for all my tests cases.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, `NaN` is not considered equal to *any* number, including itself. That's because it represnts a number outside the range of representation.

Hence there's no guarantee that you don't have two *different* numbers outside the representation, such as `0 / 0` and the square root of -1.

In fact, many systems rely on this inequality to implement `isNan()` as something like:

```
define isNaN(x):
    return x != x
```

From the [NaN Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985), IEEE 754 defines that:

- `−∞ = −∞`,
- `+∞ = +∞` and
- `x ≠ NaN` for any `x`, including `NaN`.

Comment: well, guess how isNan() is implemented in Go? http://golang.org/src/pkg/math/bits.go?h=IsNaN#L31

Answer (score 4):

This is a duplicate of [What is the rationale for all comparisons returning false for IEEE754 NaN values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values) - NaN never equals itself in IEE754, the linked answer explains why.

Comment: Didn't knew that! Thanks